# Create Menu with css and li elements compatible for all browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I am trying to create a simple menu using li elements, but it only works on IE7, in FF and Chrome, the alignment get weird.
Also the :hover and :Active only works on IE7.

Could anybody give me a hit on this?

I would really appreciate it.

CSS:

```
#heading{
    width: 700px;
   height:auto; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    display:block;
}
#imglogo{
 float:left;

}

#barDescription{
    float:right;

}



#navigation{
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 70px;
}

#navigation li{
    float: right;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;  
}
#navigation li a{

    color:#A08019;
    background-image: url('Images/Menu1.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position: center center;
        text-decoration:none;   
        font-weight:bold;
    display: block;
    height:25px;
    vertical-align:middle;
        padding-right:10px;
        padding-left:10px;
}

navigation li a:hover{
    color:white;
    background-image: url('Images/Menu2.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position: center center;
    text-decoration:none;   
    font-weight:bolder;
    display: block;
    height:25px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-left:10px;


}
navigation li a:active{
    color:#B39A48;
    background-image: url('Images/Menu2.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position: center center;
    text-decoration:none;   
    font-weight:bolder;
    display: block;
    height:25px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-left:10px;


}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="heading" >
    <div id="imglogo">
        <img id="logo" src="Images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
    </div>
    <div id="barDescription">
       <h4>Especialidad en tapas,vinos y menus</h4>
       <h5>Restaurante de cocina creativa tradicional. Vinos y tapas</h5>
    </div>

    <ul id="navigation">
       <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Ubicacion</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Reservas</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Menus</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Local</a></li>
    </ul>

    </div>
```

Comment: Can you link a working example by chance?

Comment: I can, but I can not do it until tomorrow morning.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? logo on the left, description on the right and nav underneath? or all on one line?

Comment: Another good link http://www.cssnewbie.com/super-simple-horizontal-navigation-bar/

Comment: logo on left, description right and nav underneath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Suns of Suckerfish](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/) teaches how to get there. ([Example](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/example/).)

**edit**: Now  that you posted the `:active` and `:hover` CSS, I can see you're missing a # in the beggining of the rule. So it is being applied to the "navigation" **tags** instead of the tags with "navigation" **id**. Change your CSS to add the # before "navigation":

```
#navigation li a:hover{
  /* ... */
}
#navigation li a:active{
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: See, you're missing a # in the css. Must be why it doesn't work... I'll update my answer.